# Regular expression for at least one letter followed by a white space, followed by at least one digit

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tried:

```
/[A-Za-z]++[ ]*+[1-9]/
```

and:

```
/^[\D*]+[\s]+[\d]/
```

but not working?

Comment: "Not working" means what? How about adding some example data to your question.

Comment: `/^\(.*\S.*\)$/` try this one

Comment: `+` is not what you think it is? http://regexper.com/#%2F%5BA-Za-z%5D%2B%2B%5B%20%5D*%2B%5B1-9%5D%2F

Comment: /\w+\s\d+/ https://regex101.com/r/aZ0mF5/3 ?

Comment: Please try reading a basic regexp tutorial.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: /^[a-zA-Z]{1,} [0-9]{1,}$/ seemed to work thanks for all responses though

Comment: @Sue, you realize you can simplify that, right? `\w+` is a sub for `[a-zA-Z]`and the `+` is more than one. `\d` is a sub for [0-9]` :)

Answer (score 1):

Just make it simple:

```
/\w+\s\d+/ // with optional 'g' modifier
```

Here's a **[working example](https://regex101.com/r/zQ4yZ1/3)**.

Answer (score 1):

This is as simple as I could get it:

```
\w+\s\d+
```